# Extract Email address from html source

Tags: java, html, email, extract

I have extracted html source from a web page, and was wondering how to extract texts like email addresses from that source. Im thinking of using jsoup like

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

but that would give me a lot of unwanted text as well.

Comment: You're using java I guess, but you didn't tag it in the question. Can you also use javascript/jquery? This is pretty straight forward using regex but I'm not experienced in Java.

Comment: I am using java. forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip all the tags (unless emails are inside tags). Then either apply regular expression or check every word if it matches an email pattern. I usually mark it as email if it contains `@` inside the word and a `.` is found afterwords. According to standard email format, many emails will not match (eg. `"hello world@domain.com"`). Yes email supports space characters before `@`!

Answer (score 0):

As Shiplu said, I think the best solution is sto use regular expressions, take a look at the Pattern and Matcher classes, if you're using Java.